# Python Reduce Math Equation

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

I am given a list of numbers `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and using only Python's **reduce** function, return a value. The value is calculated by:
`(((...(a[0] + a[1]) * a[2] + a[3]) * a[4] + ...)`

So in the above example where `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, the answer should be `((1 + 2) * 3 + 4) * 5 + 6 = 71`

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to learn it:
`reduce(lambda x,y: x * y, map(lambda x,y: x+y, numbers))`

Comment: So ? What did you already do ?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to learn it:   
`reduce(lambda x,y: x * y, map(lambda x,y: x+y, numbers))`

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45984550/edit) your question and add your code there but continue to receive downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky bit is, of course, that you have to alternate between two functions in `reduce`. Since you can't really keep track of the current position in the list<sup>1)</sup>, in order to decide which operation to use, your best chance is to use an iterator that alternates between `+` and `*`.

You could use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to alternate between `add` and `mul` and use those in `reduce`

```
>>> import itertools, operator
>>> op = itertools.cycle([operator.add, operator.mul])
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: next(op)(x, y), a)
71
```

If you can't use those modules, you can make a generator expression alternating between `+` and `*` using `lambda`s in a ternary expression. The rest remains the same.

```
>>> op = ((lambda x,y:x+y) if i % 2 == 0 else (lambda x,y:x*y) for i in range(len(a)))
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: next(op)(x, y), a)
71
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Well, you can, using `enumerate(a)`, or `zip(range(len(a)), a)`, if you prefer...

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: (y[0], x[1]+y[1]) if x[0]%2==0 else (y[0], x[1]*y[1]), enumerate(a))[1]
71
```

Or shorter, using tuple-unpacking in the `lambda`s, but this only works in Python 2.x:

```
>>> reduce(lambda (i,x),(j,y): (j, x+y) if i%2==0 else (j, x*y), enumerate(a))[1]
```

Comment: using only reduce

Comment: You can't do anything with *only* `reduce`; what exactly *is* allowed to be used to define the function argument?

Comment: just reduce is allowed.

Comment: @Eduardo I don't think you understand how `reduce` works. You have to define *some* function to pass as the first argument.

Answer (score 2):

Improving the solution of Akash Patel, i have come up with this, with only reduce.

```
reduce(lambda acc,x: (acc+x[1] if x[0]%2 else acc*x[1]), enumerate(numbers), 1)
```

We need to add odd number of elements and multiply even number of elements with previous elements.

Answer (score 0):

This was a tough problem because you wanted to use everything in `reduce`. So just use reduce twice!

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0], x[1] + y[1]) if y[0]%2==1 else (x[0], x[1]*y[1]) , enumerate(a)))
```